I am getting error while creating ec2 instance using simple ansible playbook
Below is my ansible code
- name: EC2 Creation
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    ec2_instance:
   # amazon.aws.ec2_instance:
      region: ap-south-1
      instance_type: t2.micro
      image_id: ami-022ce6f32988af5fa
      count: 1
      wait: yes
      tags:
        name: Test
      vpc_subnet_id: subnet-078e0bc5c6d3d2d66
      network:
        assign_public_ip: true
      key_name: linux
      secutiry_group: ALL_TCP

While using this to create ec2 instance, getting below error
[WARNING]: Found both group and host with same name: localhost

ERROR! A malformed block was encountered while loading tasks: {'ec2_instance':
{'region': 'ap-south-1', 'instance_type': 't2.micro', 'image_id':
'ami-022ce6f32988af5fa', 'count': 1, 'wait': True, 'tags': {'name': 'Test'},
'vpc_subnet_id': 'subnet-078e0bc5c6d3d2d66', 'network': {'assign_public_ip':
True}, 'key_name': 'linux', 'secutiry_group': 'ALL_TCP'}} should be a list or
None but is <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleMapping'>

The error appears to be in '/root/ec2.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: EC2 Creation
  ^ here

Can anyone help me here

Even if this looks completely unrelated to programming to me: secutiry_group is not how that should be spelled?

You have a syntax error; the values of the tasks: key should be a list. Take a look at the documentation for some examples.

I think you should be able to use --syntax-check to check your yaml link
